# What architectures may be used to break up a monolithic ASP.NET website?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ssl, architecture, url-routing

I want to divide up a monolithic ASP.NET MVC website into multiple websites that can be developed independently, but retain a common public URL with associated SSL certificate - and it's a single host certificate, not a wildcard.
[image: Possible architecture]

The main URL for anonymous users of the public website will remain the same and will be a standard ASP.NET MVC website, though the technology used for this will be upgraded over time.

As to the other services, there may be quite a number of these and they may be running in the cloud, on a Raspberry Pi or something else. A lot of the response streams will be returned as text/html, though JSON will also be returned from some APIs.

For security, I was planning on using [IdentityServer](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4) as a Security Token Service (STS) (probably version 4 when it settles down), so that needs to be factored in - not least authentication cookie handling.

I don't even know what to call what I've dubbed this front end 'distributor', but I'm assuming it's going to be lightweight. I've seen a quick demo of a node server being used in a simplistic version of this role, but I don't know enough about node to have any idea what the limitations are of this strategy.

My preference is for a C# ASP.NET MVC solution because I'm familiar with that technology.

Comment: _"what to call what I've dubbed this front end 'distributor'"_ -  a reverse proxy. Plenty existing to choose from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your front end app could be a simple reverse proxy.

I've written a [blog post](https://tomssl.com/2015/06/15/create-your-own-free-reverse-proxy-with-azure-web-apps/) about creating a free reverse proxy using Azure Web Apps. You could actually do this for free, at least while you tested that everything worked as expected.

You can use [IIS URL rewriting](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) and [Application Request Routing](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing).

You also want to rewrite the content on the way out, so that any references to `http://somehost.azurewebsites.net` are rewritten as `http://www.example.com/app1`, etc.

Here is an example web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<configuration>  
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Proxy" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="example.com/(app1)/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://somehost.azurewebsites.net/{R:2}" />
                    <serverVariables>
                        <set name="HTTP_X_UNPROXIED_URL" value="{R:0}" /> 
                        <set name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" /> 
                        <set name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_HOST" value="{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
                        <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" />
                    </serverVariables>
                </rule>
            </rules>
            <outboundRules>
                <rule name="ChangeReferencesToOriginalUrl" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" preCondition="CheckContentType">
                       <match filterByTags="None" pattern="http://example.com/app1" />
                       <action type="Rewrite" value="http://{HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_HOST}" />
                  </rule>
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="CheckContentType">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^(text/html|text/plain|text/xml|application/rss\+xml)" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Note that processing `http://www.example.com/app1/path/and/query?qs=1` through the rule `example.com/(app1)/(.*)` means that this happens:

{R:0} contains `http://www.example.com/app1/path/and/query?qs=1`

{R:1} contains `app1`

{R:2} contains `path/and/query?qs=1`

Comment: Is it possible to do this request routing with a database so that configuration can be done from a control panel?

Comment: I believe it is, although I've not done it myself. This might help: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/developing-a-custom-rewrite-provider-for-url-rewrite-module